# How to create a matplotlib figure that can display a scrollable pandas dataframe like an excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, figure

I'm trying to make a scrollable dataframe take the place of the current space occupied on the matplot window by the following code:

```
x = list(range(0, 11))
y = [10] * 11


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, bottom=0.35)
p, = plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=2, color='blue')

plt.axis([0, 10, 0, 700])
```